# Determining a UIScrollView's subview frame in the coordinate system of UIScrollView's container view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uikit

In a UIScrollView, I have a subview. How do I determine the frame of the subview in terms of the UIScrollView's container view coordinate system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the following.

```
[scrollViewSuperview convertRect:subview.frame fromView:subview]
```

You can find more info about this on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html.

Comment: This link is now broken

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `view.frame` is always related to parent view, so frame of a subview will be a rect inside the scroll view where your subview is placed.

Comment: Not always, a UIScrollView's subview frame is in terms of the UIScrollviews's contentRect, and not related to the UIScrollView's frame or bounds.